# Dmesg to real timestamp

Tags: centos, timestamp, convert, dmesg

I would like convert my Centos 6.10 dmesg in real timestamp, how do I do this? I tried with -T but no luck. I have long entry like (1630230907.320:2)

Answer (score 1):

When neither the `-T` and/or `--ctime` flags to print human-readable timestamps are supported, you can manually convert the timestamp.

The timestamp in `dmesg` is the offset in seconds since last reboot so :

1. Determine the last reboot:

   ```
    [root@server ~]# last -n 1 reboot
    reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1160.76.1 Sat Aug 27 10:56 - 14:25 (29+03:28)

    wtmp begins Tue Nov  7 09:30:18 2017
   ```
2. For example my  `dmesg` has an entry:

   ```
   [2316645.206965] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 1 devices found
   ```
3. Then use `date --date "[date of last-reboot]  [timestamp] seconds` to convert the timestamp:

   ```
   date --date "Sat Aug 27 10:56 2316645.206965 seconds"

   Fri Sep 23 06:27:37 CEST 2022
   ```
4. Which corresponds exactly with `dmesg -T` :

   ```
   [Fri Sep 23 06:27:37 2022] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 1 devices found
   ```

---

I assume though that your time stamp is incorrect for some reason, 1630230907.32 seconds is over 50 years.

Reasons for incorrect timestamps are already given in the manual page `man dmesg`

```
   -T, --ctime
       Print human-readable timestamps.

       Be aware that the timestamp could be inaccurate! The time
       source used for the logs is not updated after system
       SUSPEND/RESUME. Timestamps are adjusted according to current
       delta between boottime and monotonic clocks, this works only
       for messages printed after last resume.
```

Suspend/resume events are not only something that only concerns laptop users, virtual systems may also experience them during live migration for example.